# How to implement NSResponder action message selectWord?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I see selectWord: as an NSResponder action message and I naively assume that if I implement selectWord: on my subclass of NSTextView I can then catch word selection (via a double mouse click).  But of course this does not work that easily.  However, I *can* catch selectAll:, at least for the command-A keyboard event (but not by manipulating the selection in some other way).

I must be missing some large piece of cocoa event handling lore and here I am asking what I am missing.

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to be able to catch a double click on a word in order override the way it is highlighted. I want to draw a box around the text instead of changing the background color as is the default.

Comment: Are you wanting to override the way the text view draws selected text? Or do you want double-clicking to leave the selection alone, and simply draw a box around the clicked word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've discovered that double-clicking to select a word does not invoke `-selectWord:`.

You could try overriding `-mouseDown:` instead, and checking the NSEvent's `clickCount` to find out whether it's a double-click.

**Another thought:**

Probably the reason the text view doesn't invoke `-selectWord:` is that it's not what that method does. From the docs, it "extend the selection to the nearest word boundaries outside it (up to, but not including, word delimiters)". Since its parameter isn't a mouse event, it couldn't even know where the click occurred. So, `-mouseDown:` couldn't be the one involved.

Comment: Yes that is where I am currently headed.  But since NSResponder has all these action methods that *appear* as if they ought to be helpful, I would like to see if am just missing some cocoa functionality I could/should be using rather than rolling my own.

Comment: As much as I am still curious as to the use of the various NSResponder messages. I think for now I can get away with using an underline instead of a box to highlight the text (and therefore I can just use setSelectedTextAttributes:)